# Can i put validity logic on fields in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose i have this input field

`Name: <input type="number" ng-model="user.interval" />`

Is it possible that i can add the field validity logic on the same line like this

`<input type="text" ng-model="user.interval" ng-valid="if multiple of 5 or any expression" />`

Comment: Have you looked at the angular Developer Guide section on [Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)? The section on Custom Validation is very helpful

Comment: @AndrewJohnston I have read that but i want to know if its possible to write validation logic in the html itself rather than in some js file.

Comment: no, you should define any non-trivial validation logic in a directive, then apply this directive to your inputs.

Comment: Is that Ng-valid the CSS class? Or your own custom directive. I'm not familiar with it.